# Logic for building WQL-query

Tags: sql, logic, subquery, sccm, wql

For a membership rule for collections in System Center Configuration Manager R2 i have to write a WQL-query which is a bit complex and gives me a hard time building the logic for.

Let's say there are two tables i need: users, and systems.

My goal is to write a query that retrieves all the systems where the 'office' (column of the users table) of the 'last logon user' (column of the systems table) is equal to a given value.

I assume i'll need a subselect, but i can't figure out the exact logic.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a little vague, but in pseudo-sql you'd just do something like this:

`SELECT *
    FROM Systems
    JOIN Users ON Systems.LastLogonUser = Users.Username
    WHERE Users.Office = 'value'`

With regards specifically to SCCM, I can't recall off of the top of my head if the user's office information is discovered from AD or not, but if it does then the rest of the logic stands.

Comment: Thank you, it's going the right way, but it's a little more complex than that. I forgot to mention, the systems SCCM discovers are stored in a table called 'systems_r' and the lastlogonuser in a table 'systems_g', with the systemId being the primary and foreign key. Also I don't want systems with a bios release date older than 2008-09-30, the bios release date is in a table pc_bios, also with system Id being primary key in systems_r and foreign key in pc_bios.